# Does the abort() function in C clean the stack?

Tags: c, stack-overflow, abort

It's possible to catch the SIGABRT and continue the program with a longjump for example.

I wonder if this can lead to a stack overflow when I always call functions that invoke abort().

I need to know that because i want to use the assert macro (taht calls abort) in unit tests. If an assert fails, I want to continue with the next unit test.

Comment: Why did you add the tag 'stackoverflow'?

Comment: @govindo because he's talking about an actual stack overflow! why did you remove it?

Comment: @user4815162342 Oh really, Sorry he must have stated "I wonder if this can lead to a stack, to overflow" instead of "I wonder if this can lead a stack overflow"

Comment: @govinda Well, I guess programmers know what a 'stack overflow' is, no need to complicate that sentence...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`abort` doesn't need to clear the stack; `longjmp` will "clear" it in that it will rewind the stack pointer back to the position of `setjmp`. If all else is correct, repeatedly invoking `longjmp` and `setjmp` will not cause stack overflow.

However, `longjmp` will skip normal execution path, which can call resource leaks in its own right. Consider this code:

```
char *s = malloc(...);
... use s ...
free(s);
```

If the "... use s ..." portion calls some function that `longjmp`s out of the code, `free` won't get a chance to get called and you will leak. The same applies to closing open files, sockets, freeing shared memory segments, reaping forked children, and so on.

For this reason `longjmp` is rarely used in C programming. My advice would be to avoid `assert` if you don't mean the program to exit. Simply use another macro in your unit tests, or switch to a testing framework that provides one.

Answer (score 1):

[longjmp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h) does not unwind the stack, but it does modify the stack pointer:

> If the function in which setjmp was called returns, it is no longer
>   possible to safely use longjmp with the corresponding jmp_buf object.
>   This is because the stack frame is invalidated when the function
>   returns. **Calling longjmp restores the stack pointer**, which—because
>   the function returned—would point to a non-existent and potentially
>   overwritten/corrupted stack frame.

Comment: Since standard C doesn't have destructors (all data types are POD in C++ parlance), there is no difference between unwinding the stack and restoring the stack pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming POSIX, calling `longjmp` to get out of the `SIGABRT` raised by `abort` is valid, because `abort` is specified to be async-signal-safe (and also because this signal is not asynchronous). (In plain C, doing almost anything from a signal handler is UB so it's usually not an interesting case to talk about.) However, it's your responsibility to make sure that none of your own program's state is left inconsistent as a result, in such a way that it would cause your program to invoke UB in some other way immediately or much later in the program flow.

With that said, I agree with user4815162342 that your proposal is a very bad form of error handling. If you don't want to abort, don't call `abort`, but instead write your own error handling functions.

Comment: its not for error handling, but just for unit testing and it works as expected. Like in other unit test frameworks I want to call assert macros in my test functions. As soon as one assert fails, this function must get interrupted and the next test function has to be called. And that's exactly what now happens.

Comment: You could just re-`#define` `assert` yourself, but I don't see anything horribly wrong with this approach for unit testing, especially since you might (for some kinds of unit testing) even be doing the same thing with `SIGSEGV`...